# Escaping characters in PS1

Tags: bash, shell, initialization, escaping

I'm starting a new session of bash using a command like this: 
`exec bash --init-file <(cat /etc/profile ~/.bashrc $ANOTHER_SCRIPT) -i`
I'd like to also change the prompt of new session without having to add another init file... I suspect my best bet is something like this:
`exec bash --init-file <(cat /etc/profile ~/.bashrc $ANOTHER_SCRIPT; echo "PS1='[TEST] '$PS1") -i`
I think my problems concern escaped characters... but I'm quite clueless about how to continue tackling the problem as prepending my label to the prompt.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated,

Andrew

Comment: It's interesting that      exec bash --init-file <(cat /etc/profile ~/.bashrc $ANOTHER_SCRIPT; echo "PS1='[TEST] '$PS1")      is different from      exec bash --init-file <(cat /etc/profile ~/.bashrc $ANOTHER_SCRIPT; echo 'PS1="[TEST] "$PS1')

Comment: Changing from "quotes'inside'quotes" to 'quotes"inside"quotes' breaks it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
exec bash --init-file <(cat /etc/profile ~/.bashrc $ANOTHER_SCRIPT; echo 'PS1="[TEST] $PS1"') -i
```

Comment: I'm also looking for a space between [TEST] and the existing PS1... but quoting takes care of it.

Comment: @ajwood: I changed my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Take a look at the difference better your answer and like code in my question... why does the difference in quoting make such a difference?

Comment: @ajwood: Single quotes escape the contents. Double quotes allow the contents to be expanded. You can use tracing (`set -x`) to compare. Try your command with `... set -x; echo "PS1 ... '...' ..."; set +x ...` versus my command with `... set -x; echo 'PS1 ... "..." ...'; set +x ...` and you'll see a big difference. (Use the real command instead of `...`.)

Comment: I'm currently learning Perl and this explains so much! Thanks!

Comment: @ajwood: I'm glad to be of help! Forgive me for pointing out the "tip jar", but you can up-vote answers (whether they're the "accepted" ones or not and regardless of whether it's your question). If you feel an answer is deserving, just click on the ▲ at the upper left.

Comment: Aha, I'm new to SO. I see no reason to be stingy. Consider yourself tipped!

Answer (score 1):

`PS1="[TEST] $PS1"`

You can't put this on the same line as your `<(cat ...)` process substitution since it's expecting only files but rather inside your `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: Does the semicolon not take care of that?